# How to prevent file deletion by ANY user

Tags: c#, file-permissions, acl, filesystemobject

Problem:  Need to prevent individual Windows files from being deleted, at least without Administrator privileges.  Files must be readable by "Everyone".
The Windows directory in which the files reside must be writeable and readable by "Everyone".

Debugging: Example Code below is my attempt to set the "Deny Delete" access control rules on an example file (string "urlFilePath" contains the full path to the actual file when this code is executed).  The code runs with no errors, but the files are still marked as deletable by Everyone (and other accounts).

Details:
I have a C# Service that migrates files from a soon-to-be-decommissioned FileNet WORM storage system to Windows file system storage.

The files need to be accessible to many users (effectively "Everyone"), but must be preserved against deletion - whether accidental or intentional.
The folder(s) in which the files will reside must be writable (some users must be allowed to add future files), so I cannot make the folders read-only.

I thought I could just add ACL rules to "deny" delete, but the following code isn't working.
Did I make a simple mistake or is there some trick I am missing?

```
    string urlFilePath = @"\\server\directory\anotherdir\myfile.pdf";
    List<string> fileAccounts = new List<string>();
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(urlFilePath);
    FileSecurity fsec = fi.GetAccessControl();
    AuthorizationRuleCollection acl = fsec.GetAccessRules(includeExplicit: true, includeInherited: true, targetType: typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule acr in acl)
    {
        if (!fileAccounts.Contains(acr.IdentityReference.Value))
            fileAccounts.Add(acr.IdentityReference.Value);
    }

    //  populate standard accounts
    foreach (string s in new string[] { "GUEST", "USERS", "DOMAIN USERS", "NETWORK", "AUTHENTICATED USERS"})
    {
        if (!fileAccounts.Contains(s))
            fileAccounts.Add(s);
    }
    FileSecurity fileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(urlFilePath);
    int numAccounts = 0;
    foreach (string account in fileAccounts)
    {
        fileSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.Delete, AccessControlType.Allow));
        fileSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.Delete, AccessControlType.Deny));
        numAccounts++;
    }
```

In the above, I followed (I thought) the MS example of adding/removing ACL rules.  I get no errors, warnings, or exceptions, but the files remain fully deleteable by everyone.  I explicitly added the list of accounts, thinking maybe the ones already associated with the file weren't sufficient.  When this runs, it reports the remove/add loop runs against 9 accounts - the 5 I added, plus 4 already associated, so the remove rule/add rule loop is executing against all the accounts.

How can I set the individual files to be non-deleteable?  It is acceptable to allow them to be deleted if the person deleting gives themselves ownership of the individual file, as that should be sufficiently safe.

I would prefer to not allow Domain Administrators to delete without taking ownership of the file, but Administrators *could* be allowed to delete files (both Local and Domain Administrators) if preventing those groups is too difficult.  The critical need is to prevent any non-administrators from deleting any of these files.

My question was closed as requiring "debugging details", but with no mention of what details were missing or requested. ???

Comment: I voted to reopen your question, but to offer some (hopefully constructive) feedback, I think it can still be greatly improved by being less "chatty", more focused, and having only a single clear question. Currently it asks several implicit/explicit questions: "How to prevent...?", "Did I make...?", "How can I...?", "Is it acceptable...?". Try amending your post so that it contains exactly one question that ends with a question mark so that it is crystal clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

After some more trial and error, I think I found a solution.  Applying "Deny" to the Delete right is insufficient.  The following seems to work.  To delete a file set this way requires a user with sufficient privileges to remove the Deny rules.

I get the list of all current Accounts with access to the folder, add several "well known" accounts, and then iterate through the accounts, removing all the rights other than READ, and then applying DENY rights to everything except READ.

Get the list of accounts.

```
    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
    DirectorySecurity dSec = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
    AuthorizationRuleCollection arc = dSec.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
    List<string> fileAccounts = new List<string>();
    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule fsar in arc)
    {
        if (!fileAccounts.Contains(fsar.IdentityReference.Value))
            fileAccounts.Add(fsar.IdentityReference.Value);
    }
    foreach (string s in new string[] { "GUEST", "USERS", "DOMAIN USERS", "NETWORK", "Authenticated Users", "SYSTEM", "Everyone" })
    {
        if (!fileAccounts.Contains(s))
            fileAccounts.Add(s);
    }
```

Iterate through the accounts, removing/adding rights.  Note that not all accounts may exist in all cases (e.g., domain/non-domain accounts), so I trap and discard errors.

```
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fname);
    FileSecurity fsec = fi.GetAccessControl();
    int numSet = 0;
    foreach (string account in fileAccounts)
    {
        try
        {
            fsec.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.Delete, AccessControlType.Allow));
            fsec.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
            fsec.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow));
            fsec.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, AccessControlType.Allow));
            fsec.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Allow));
            fsec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.Delete, AccessControlType.Deny));
            fsec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny));
            fsec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Deny));
            fsec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, AccessControlType.Deny));
            fsec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Deny));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  log error and continue if necessare - Console.WriteLine(account + ": " + ex.Message);
        }
        numSet++;
    }
    fi.SetAccessControl(fsec);
```

I suspect there is a cleaner, simpler way to do this, but at least this is working for what I need.

Comment: Does this work if the permissions are inherited from the parent folder?

Comment: Yes, but turns out this does not work properly when processed in my Service account.  By creating explicit ACL rules at the object/account level, these override the inherited ACL properties.  I am having problems finding the exact mix of allow/deny rules that make the files read-only, visible, and not deleteable.  For a good explanation of how inherited and explicit file controls work, google "NTFS file acls" and check out the explanations posted there.